# True/False column based on most recent date of other column in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have data like this in Power Query:

[image]

And I'd like to create a new column that is true/false.  It's TRUE if a patient's most recent status date is associated with their "On Followup", i.e. they are **currently** on followup.

So for instance the new column would look like this:

[image]

Where Bob and Joe are true, but Tiffany and John are false. John has never been on followup, and Tiffany was but its not her most recent status.

Comment: Can you paste your sample data as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"data", each _, type table } ,{"status" ,each if Table.Sort(_,{{"Status_Date", Order.Descending}}){0}[Status] = "On Followup" then true else false } }),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Status", "Status_Date"}, {"Status.1", "Status_Date"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Status_Date", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure this will work but the excel.currentworkbook() is throwing me, Im actually in power query within Power bi, is there an equivalent?

Comment: try replacing Excel.CurrentWorkbook with Excel.WorkBook

Comment: can you expand this solution to expand all the columns of the data group without introduce them?
My application:
`Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Grouped Rows", 
        "data", 
        {"ALER_ID", "ALES_ID", "ALER_FIID_CARD", "ALEH_USUARIO", "ALER_FECHAALTA", "ALEH_FECHAHORA_DESDE", "ALEH_FECHAHORA_HASTA", "ALEH_HORA_DESDE", "ALEH_HORA_HASTA", "ALEH_FECHA_DESDE", "ALEH_FECHA_HASTA", "ALER_FECHAHORA_ALTA"}, {"data.ALER_ID", "data.ALES_ID", "data.ALER_FIID_CARD", "data.ALEH_USUARIO", ...."and more fields..."}),`

Comment: List = List.Union(List.Transform( #"Grouped Rows"[data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn( #"Grouped Rows", "data", List,List)   For additional help, please start another question